# Настройка подсказок для переменных в функциях в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

В Intellij IDEA есть подсказки в виде имен для параметров в функциях. Если мы передаем само значение или проводим вычисления - подсказка выводится, но как только мы передаем только переменную, то подсказка не появляется. Не могу найти в настройках где это фиксится. Подскажите, как можно настроить данный момент?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File - Settings/Preferences - Editor - Inlay Hints

Upd. Такой опции нет. Голосование за добавление данной опции идет [тут](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22289).

Можно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, поставив курсор внутри скобок, тогда появится информация о параметрах. Но это не совсем то.

Comment: Ну, да, данный путь я в настройках открывал. Можете подсказать конкретный пункт, который отвечает за данную настройку?

Comment: @SryForStupidQuestion А похоже, что никакой. Вообще Show argument name hints, но он включает/отключает подсказку. И как ее показывать и для переменной тоже - непонятно. Сорян. Странно сделали, я раньше даже внимания не обращал.

Comment: Сам удивлен. Знать бы еще английский, чтобы зарепортить им :D

Comment: Отличные новости: компания российская, так что можно и на русском :) Я, правда, тут ничего на русском не нашел, но посмотрите на имена разработчиков https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA